# "Does anyone have used this before?" or "has anyone used this before?"

Tags: grammar

"Does anyone have used this before?" or "has anyone used this before?" which sentence is correct? or both of them are incorrect ? and what is the correct sentence?

Comment: What makes you think one is correct and the other incorrect?  (Proofreading questions are off-topic unless you identify a point of concern.)

Comment: only the latter is correct

Comment: In the first sentence, you use two auxiliaries (*does* and *have*) for the same verb. If wou want to use the auxiliary *do*, the first sentence should be *Did anyone use this before*.

Answer (score 1):

We use "**do** support" to form questions and negatives only when there isn't already an auxiliary, such as *be*, *have*, or a modal.

When *have* is acting as a lexical verb it may take "do support":

> Do you have any milk?

but it doesn't have to, particularly in British English:

> Have you [got] any milk?

But when *have* is an auxiliary, forming a perfect tense, it cannot take "do support":

> Has anyone used this before?

not

> *Does anyone have used this before?

(You didn't ask about this, but it's worth specifying:) in the phrasal verb *have to*, meaning *be obliged to*", *have* is not an auxiliary, and may take "do support" in questions and negatives:

> I don't have to go.

or

> I haven't got to go.

You might even find *I haven't to go* in old books, but I doubt if there's anybody that says it now.

Comment: Does one downvote answers to questions obviously not suitable for ELU?